# Recover a character as soon as it is entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to process each character entered in my text input to display it properly I can't use the keydown event because I would like the event to work for mobile as well. So I have to retrieve the character as soon as my input is modified.

I have used the keydown and change event before, but I have a problem with the mobile version for the keydown event and the change event acts when I exit or validate the entry. After research I can't find a way to retrieve the event if my field is modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event.

```js
var $input = $('#myinput');
$input.on('input', function(e) {
  var value = e.target.value;
  // do something with the value, for example print:
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myinput" placeholder="Start typing..." />
```

Comment: This perfectly meets my request, thank you !